# Pandas aggregate two columns at max

Tags: python, pandas, optimization, aggregate, knapsack-problem

I have a data frame with two columns

```
df = DataFrame.from_records([
  {"time": 10, "amount": 200},
  {"time": 70, "amount": 1000},
  {"time": 10, "amount": 300},
  {"time": 10, "amount": 100},
])
```

I want to, given a period of time `80`ms, calculate the max amount that is possible, in this case, the output should be 1300 because, in this period, the maximum amount possible is 1300.

Is it possible with Pandas? I thought about using aggregate, but I do not know how to use it

Comment: it is not clear (to me) from looking at this how the max amount possible is 1300? I see the  amount of 1000 with time = 70, and the sum of all the time = 10 rows is 600 (and a max of 300). Are we doing the max of time=10 + max of time=70?

Comment: @scotscotmcc I have just edited the question; in this case, I want to know the maximum value possible given the limit of 80, which should be 1300

Comment: ok, in this case it seems straightforward since the only way to sum to 80 in the rows you  have is 70 + 10. would you ever have cases where there are more options for the summing? like if you had a row of 60 here, then you could have 70 + 10 or 60 + 10 + 10. if you have dozens or hundreds of rows, there would likely be lots of ways to sum to the given period. or is that not a concern?

Comment: @scotscotmcc no problem in this case, maybe should I order the dataframe before aggregate?

Comment: If the time column represent consecutive durations, you should try to first normalize the data to have a constant duration being a divisor of 80 (here it would be 10), then you could use a rolling window

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a [knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem), you can solve it with a dedicated library (e.g., [`knapsack`](https://pypi.org/project/knapsack/)):

```
from knapsack import knapsack
total, idx = knapsack(df['time'], df['amount']).solve(80)

df.out = df.iloc[idx]
```

output:

```
   time  amount
1    70    1000
2    10     300
```

Other examples:

```
# with max = 75
   time  amount
1    70    1000

# with max = 40
   time  amount
0    10     200
2    10     300
3    10     100
```

Comment: How to use iloc? I tried df.iloc but no luck

Comment: @Rodrigo there was a typo from my copy/paste, see update

Comment: I got `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded`, is there some non-recursive implementation?

Comment: How many rows do you have? This might be tricky to solve if you have too many rows, this might no be possible to solve it easily (see about the problem [complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#Computational_complexity): "*there is no known algorithm both correct and fast (polynomial-time) in all cases*")

Comment: I have 5000 rows, I ended with knapsack non-recursive that I have found on the internet and it worked, thank you for pointing out the algorithm!

Comment: @Rodrigo great! Maybe you can provide the link to the knapsack algorithm/code that you used for future readers

Comment: Of course, there is a non-recursive version here https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/0-1-knapsack-problem-dp-10/

Answer (score 1):

You could try to upsample you data to 10ms and then use a rolling window.

```
# set a time index to the dataframe
df2 = df.set_index(pd.to_timedelta(df['time'], unit='ms').cumsum())
```

it gives:

```
                        time  amount
time                                
0 days 00:00:00.010000    10     200
0 days 00:00:00.080000    70    1000
0 days 00:00:00.090000    10     300
0 days 00:00:00.100000    10     100
```

We can now upsample the amount, assuming a linear increase between consecutive timestamps:

```
amounts = (df2.amount / df2.time).resample('10ms').bfill()
```

giving:

```
time
0 days 00:00:00.010000    20.000000
0 days 00:00:00.020000    14.285714
0 days 00:00:00.030000    14.285714
0 days 00:00:00.040000    14.285714
0 days 00:00:00.050000    14.285714
0 days 00:00:00.060000    14.285714
0 days 00:00:00.070000    14.285714
0 days 00:00:00.080000    14.285714
0 days 00:00:00.090000    30.000000
0 days 00:00:00.100000    10.000000
Freq: 10L, dtype: float64
```

Using a rolling window, we can now find the amount per 80ms duration:

```
amounts.rolling('80ms').sum()
```

which gives:

```
time
2022-01-01 00:00:00.010     20.000000
2022-01-01 00:00:00.020     34.285714
2022-01-01 00:00:00.030     48.571429
2022-01-01 00:00:00.040     62.857143
2022-01-01 00:00:00.050     77.142857
2022-01-01 00:00:00.060     91.428571
2022-01-01 00:00:00.070    105.714286
2022-01-01 00:00:00.080    120.000000
2022-01-01 00:00:00.090    130.000000
2022-01-01 00:00:00.100    125.714286
Freq: 10L, dtype: float64
```

We can see that the maximum value is reached after 90 ms and is 130.

If you only want the max value:

```
amounts.rolling('80ms').sum().max()
```

giving directly:

```
130.0
```